# Can an SQL engine/optimizer use temporary tables to execute a query?

Tags: sql-server

I could see that manually splitting a complicated queries to a chain of kind `select [...] into #t` and then `select [...] from #t [...]` would prove visibly faster. It may have been caused by a bad design.

But nevertheless, is it possible for an SQL engine/optimizer to use such temporary tables if it would consider it useful?

Also if the kind of manual splitting I have described above results in a significant performance increase does it imply that the design of the original view/underlying tables is significantly flawed?

Comment: I like this question, but it's a bit broad and would basically involve explaining the inner workings of optimisation in the SQL Server engine. I use temp table like that to break down larger queries and it generally improves performance. I look at it as breaking down a massive task in to smaller more manageable chunks. If you give SQL Server a massive query, it will try to evaluate the entire query to optimise it, where as if you give it 3 smaller queries (that you've in effect optimised slighlty), it'll give SQL Server less work to do.

Comment: SQL Server can do similar thing automatically too, and you can see it as spools in query plan. More details in Rob Farley's [blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2013/06/11/spooling-in-sql-execution-plans.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a chain of temp table does NOT prove a bad design. It also doesn't guaranty you get better performance. You should consider using temp table wisely. sometimes it improves performance and sometime it only increases disk read/write.

One obvious usage of temp table in these kind of scenario is, you store data into a temp table to eliminate multiple execution of a slow query. By this mean, if you execute an expensive query, multiple times in your code, you should consider using temp table and use stored data instead of executing the query in multiple place of your code.

The other case might be because of making code more understandable and easier to read (if performance is not an issue)

One other case is, you use temp table to be able to add index to your data. In such a case, you store data into temp table and then create index on it to gain better read performance.

In general, if you should not use temp table for a query that executes only once in your code.

Finally, SQL Server uses temp table for it's own use, not the way you may want to store the data. So don't count on SQL Server to do, what you may want to do using temp table.

Comment: The original select was based on view that had multiple case statements. Then on that view I would make aggregations and filtering (on varchar fields as well). Putting the original view into temp table hugely boosted the performance of the final select. But it's one time execution. Should I then work on the original view and the underlying tables to make it more efficient?

Comment: if your final query, simply selects from from temp table instead of selecting from view, using temp table should not improve performance. I will surprise  if you replace your view with a temp table and gain better performance if your query uses the view once. However sometimes having data into a temp table cause SQL Server generate better execution plan. usually this happens when your statistics are not up-to-date. if you get better performance using temp table go ahead with it but I believe you should be able to explain this behavior if you look at the execution plan.

Comment: There is filtering and aggregation done on the #temp table. Source view is like `select f1, f2, ...., case ..., case ..., ... from t1 ... join t2 ... joint t3 .... I insert results from this view into #temp table and then I select from the #temp table doing additional filtering and aggregation. And the execution time drops from long minutes to several seconds.

Comment: Think this way: storing data into temp table takes (time for reading data from view + time for writing data to temp table). so when you use temp table instead of using view, SQL Server spends more time (time for writing data to temp table). having temp table in this case only adds more effort to Server to write data to temp table. If you get better performance, there MUST be some reason that I can't explain unless I see all the detail of your codes. Hope this makes it more clear.